# feeding variable length spectrograms to tensorflow keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, spectrogram

My inputs are N mp3 files which i've turned into spectrograms of shape `(128,X)`. Each one has a different `X` depending on the duration of the mp3 example.

How do I feed these spectrograms to keras. If they were 1D data of a fixed length, I would make a single feature `ndarray` where each example would correspond to a single row in the `ndarray` 'matrix'. But since the length isn't fixed and each example isn't a vector but a 2d `ndarray`, i'm not sure how to create a single feature collection to pass to Keras. Is there a trick to it?

Comment: A possible approach is to pad them all to the same length

Comment: hey thanks. so find the length of the longest spectrogram and then pad the rest with zeros to be the same shape? It's still 2d, so would I have to unroll each row into one long feature vector per example?

Comment: About the first part: Yes, find what's the longest spectrogram you have and pad everything to that (or set a maximum length even bigger and pad some more). About the "still 2D part", that depends on how your network input looks like. CNNs can deal with 2D data, other architectures can't. The shape of the input is dictated by the network

Comment: Yeah i'm going to train a CNN. If it will be 2d or 1d convolutions, i'm wishing to try both to see which performs better.